# How do I define this equation in GAMs？

Tags: gams-math

I want to define this function `sum(R,(R,Rp))+sum(Rp,(R,Rp))=e=db(R)`, but there are always errors:
`Set is under control already` and `Uncontrolled set entered as constant`. Do R and Rp not match? I don't know how to define this.

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful if you share at least the complete equation definition.